# same site fetch ignores cookie

Tags: vuejs3, session-cookies, fetch-api

I have 2 vue apps

1. portal  on https://portal.example.com
2. authN is on https://auth.example.com

After login in https://auth.example.com a Cookie is stored as

- httpOnly; domain=.example.com; Same-site=Strict; Path=/

If I open https://portal.example.com or https://auth.example.com cookie is attached to the request. So cookie can be used from different subdomains.

**But**
If I do GET call fetch("https://auth.example.com/whoami ") from https://portal.example.com cookie is not attached to this rest call.

In inspector I see that call had

- Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
- Host: auth.example.com
- Origin: https://portal.example.com
- Referer: https://portal.example.com

**Why Cookie is not being attached?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing peace
in first app in fetch need to add to header

```
{credentials: 'include'}
```

And in second app(vue/nuxt) in Response I need

```
setResponseHeaders(event, {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": <url-first-app>,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
});
```