# How to handle Cookies/Sessions if PHP-backend is on a different server

Tags: javascript, php, http, session, request

I have a general question about handling cookies if you are working on two servers while developing (one server for front- and backend)
I have build a webapplication with a login system. There are two main routes:

"/" is the landing page for the public with option to login or create an account

"/dashboard" a protected starting page after you logged in

If you register (create a new Account), the app automaticly logs you in (and therefore redirects you to "/dashboard"

All of this works fine. To avoid users from entering the portected area by manually typing the /dashboard route into the browsers url window i want it to check instantly, wether a user is logged or not.

Allthough during the process of creating an account, the $_SESSION variable for the logged user is set, right after redirecting to "/dashboard" (and therefore instant check for the same $_SESSION variable that was set milliseconds ago) i can see out of the response of the checking that this particular $_SESSION variable is not set.

So is there anything special i need to keep in mind when having the backend on a different server?

Why am i emphasising the different server so much?
Well, my application already worked fine. I used to work with plain JS and plain PHP. That was easy to work with because is just had my complete project into the htdocs folder of XAMPPs apache webserver.

I am refactoring my application from plain JS to Vue 3.

So this is different now:

- My Vue CLI runs a webserver for the vue application on "localhost:8080"
- My backend stays in htocs because, well, i need a server that runs php on "localhost"
- In JS (and Vue) i work with fetch(). As Endpoint for the Php i used to use a reltive path (bc it was all in one project directory) like `fetch("../src/backend/main.php")` and now i use the path to the localhost server like `fetch("http/localhost/backend/main.php")`
- Because localhost:8080 is for my backend different from "localhost" i have set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header tp "*"

Because those are the only things that are new i assume that my problem has to do with the additional server for my development environment but if you see another cause please let me know.

I want to emphasise that every other communication between front- and backend works perfectly fine, its just that i ahve the feeling that sessions are treated differently now and i would love to know why.

Here is the part where i fetch my backend:

```
    },
    actions: {
        async post(context, dataobject) {
          let summary = {};
          let req = undefined;
          if(dataobject)
          {
              req = {
                  method: "post",
                  body: JSON.stringify(dataobject),
                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                      "credentials" : "include",
                  },
              }
              //###############################################
              let response = await fetch(context.state.API, req);
              [...]
```

and this is my updated entry point of the backend (main.php):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: does the front end (i.e. browser) "allow credentials"?

Comment: i have no part in my frontend where credential headers are set. Only headers are set ist ContentType: application/json

Comment: then that may be an issue

Comment: oh okay, how is that an issue? and why is that an issue now that i work with vue and wasnt an issue when i was working with plain js?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75896316/1941241 — in PHP, your CORS response should allow credentials, and in Vue, `fetch` needs to be told to include credentials with requests to your PHP API. This will allow fetch to include the cookie that contains the PHP session id.

Comment: @rickdenhaan first of all thx. i am confused about the soluction of your link regarding the client side. I assumend that there exists a Request Header "credentials" that is just needed to include as an additional header but there is no such header as "credentials" so

```

                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                      "Credentials" : "include",
                  },
```

Just dont work. Its a property of the XMLHttpRequest Object. Whats the fetch() equivalent of credentials?

Comment: No, it is not a header but a [request option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included). It goes alongside `headers`, not in it. E.g. `fetch(url, { credentials: "include", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } })`

Comment: @rickdenhaan thank you very much. Regarding "credentials: inlcude" i only encountered sources that connected that with XMLHttpRequest Object. It works perfectly and i learned that cookies need this little special treatment to exchange via CORS. Problem solved, have a nice one